# Local Datastore - SQL Server Express, MySQL, XML or NoSQL in .Net

Tags: .net, nosql, tethering, xml-database

Scenario:

1. I am building an OFFLINE (yeah you read right in 2012) application which needs to store data locally.
2. And will sync with a central mysql database when connected.
3. This client app has to work in XP/Win7/Win 8 and Windows phone. But may also be ported to Droid and iOS.

Data volume is not huge and relationship is not that complicated either. Also at some point thi
So I am thinking about using:

1. SQL Server Express / Compact (which may not work in linux based droid / ios)
2. MS-Access (don't like it)
3. XML file based data store and handwritten data handling (fun but more work)
4. XML database (expensive)
5. NO SQL option (Redis may be)

Before I jump into Redis, wanted to hear from guru s if anybody faced similar situation and implemented something similar.

Thanks in advance
Rahul

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely consider [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) option.

> SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained,
>   serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.

Comment: I agree, SQLite is a good way to go, since it is very cross-compatible.  MySQL also comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks - I was going redis and mongodb route. Let me check sqllite

Comment: Looks like SQLite is the tool that I am going to use.
Is there any ORM (free/opensource) that works well with SQLite

Comment: @pagladasu There are plenty of them: from http://sqliteorm.codeplex.com/ to NHibernate and EF.